# Unable to forward HTTP to HTTPS with Gunicorn on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, plotly-dash

I am running a Python app using Dash library on Heroku and trying to redirect any HTTP request to HTTPS, but I'm unable to get the setting right.

In my Proc file I have:

```
web: gunicorn --config=gunicorn.conf.py app:server
```

And my config file:

```
forwarded_allow_ips = '*'
secure_scheme_headers = { 'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
```

My expectation is that HTTP requests get redirected or fail, but they currently do not and work fine.

Comment: [`secure_scheme_headers`](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#secure-scheme-headers) doesn't _perform_ a redirect. It tells Gunicorn what headers it should use to determine whether an upstream proxy (like Nginx) has successfully received an HTTPS request from the client.

Comment: mmm so given the environment im working in is there a where to perform a redirect @Chris ?

Comment: Unfortuantely, I don't see anything obvious. It's a [classic situation](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/spider-man-pointing-at-spider-man) where Heroku wants you to do it in your code but you're using tech that wouldn't normally be responsible for this. I suspect there's a way to do it in Dash if you know its internals, or if you can expose an underlying library that it may use for it server, but I don't know Dash so can't make a better suggestion than that.

Comment: (IMO, this is something that Heroku _should_ handle for you. But their stance has been consistent as long as I've used their products.)